# Metamask NOT prompting user to send to contract

Tags: transactions, metamask

I am able to call Merchant.buy and receive a success callback + see the transaction in my ganache-cli log. The user was never prompted.

I am using Brave + Metamask pointing to local network.

Expected behavior: Upon calling .send, Metamask prompts user.

```
class Merchant {
  static load() {
    if (typeof window.web3 !== 'undefined') {
      window.web3 = new Web3(Web3.currentProvider);
      console.log("Current provider" + Web3.currentProvider);
      if (!Web3.currentProvider) {
        window.web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"));
      }
      console.log("web3 is" + window.web3);
    } else {
      window.web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"));
      console.log("New web3 is" + window.web3);
    }

    let c = new window.web3.eth.Contract(Merchant.abi(), Merchant.address());
    Merchant.contract = c;
    console.log("Loaded contract" + Merchant.contract);

    window.web3.eth.getAccounts().then(function(a,b) {
      Merchant.accounts = a;
      console.log("Merchant accounts: " + Merchant.accounts);
    });
  }

  static buy(amount) {
    console.log("buying amount is" + amount);
    let accounts = Merchant.accounts;
    let c = Merchant.contract;

    let account = accounts[0];
    let buyParams = {from: account,value: amount};

    let v = c.methods.buyKey().send(buyParams);
    v.then(function(a,b) {
      console.log("Bought successfully result" + (a));
    });  
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Web3.currentProvider` should be `web3.currentProvider` (lowercase W).

I think what's happening is that `Web3.currentProvider` doesn't exist, so you're falling back to a direct connection to localhost (`ganache-cli`) and not using MetaMask at all.

Comment: Hey, really good catch. This is how I imported it: import Web3 from 'web3';

Comment: Oh, you're right! It is creating a new one... ok, then how am I supposed to init it? It shouldn't matter if I import it as web3 or Web3

Comment: MetaMask injects the variable at `window.web3`, so you need to use `window.web3.currentProvider`.

Comment: (So the capitalization *does* matter, since it's not up to you. MetaMask uses a lowercase W.)

Comment: Yep, I see that now. thank you. I made the mistake of importing with node and THEN checking for web3

Comment: If I understand what you're doing correctly, importing first should be fine, as long as you're not overwriting `window.web3`, which it doesn't look like you are. (You're using `Web3`, which is the norm.)

Comment: Ah, thank you. I think my use case is that I need metamask to access the wallet. Is there any reason a developer would want to use their own web3 without connecting to metamask?

Comment: Well, if you weren't running in the browser, you couldn't use MetaMask. If you were running in Mist, you would use that instead. If you just need to read data from the blockchain, you might just connect directly to a public node (one you run or one provided by a third party). And there are probably other solutions (e.g. on mobile) that don't rely on MetaMask.